# Makefile called in target

Tags: c, compilation, makefile, target

I have a makefile, called "Makefile", and some target in it like:

```
file.o: file.c Makefile
      gcc <some flags & options> file.c
```

What exactly does `file.o: file.c Makefile` do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That line describes the dependencies for `file.o`.

If any file listed after the `:` (`file.c` and `Makefile` in this case) has been modified later than `file.o`, then `file.o` is rebuilt according to the command in the following line.

Comment: I'm kinda curious about this one as I've never seen `Makefile` as a dependency. Is that just listing the makefile itself as a dependent of `file.o` so that if it is modified at all since the last make command it will remake `file.o`?

Comment: @Taelsin That is correct.  From what I've seen it's not that common, although it makes sense that a change to the makefile can potentially affect all the files it is instructed to build.

Comment: Thank you very much for answer, and thank you @Taelsin for further clarification.